# Bind two checboxes to a nullable bool property in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I try to connect two checkboxes to my ViewModel. Their behavior is like a radiobutton (exclusive) and TheeState. So both not checked or one of them checked

At the moment I am doing the job like that:

```
                            <dxlc:LayoutGroup>
                                <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="with errors">
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding OnlyMusicWithErrorsChecked}"></CheckBox>
                                </dxlc:LayoutItem>
                                <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="without errors">
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding OnlyMusicWithoutErrorsChecked}"></CheckBox>
                                </dxlc:LayoutItem>
                            </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
```

und ViewModel:

```
    private bool _onlyMusicWithErrorsChecked;

    public bool OnlyMusicWithErrorsChecked
    {
        get { return _onlyMusicWithErrorsChecked; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _onlyMusicWithErrorsChecked, value, () => OnlyMusicWithErrorsChecked);
            if (OnlyMusicWithErrorsChecked)
                OnlyMusicWithoutErrorsChecked = false;
            RaisePropertyChanged("AdditionalCriteriaHeader");
            if (!_filteringData) 
                SelectData();
        }
    }

    private bool _onlyMusicWithoutErrorsChecked;

    public bool OnlyMusicWithoutErrorsChecked
    {
        get { return _onlyMusicWithoutErrorsChecked; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _onlyMusicWithoutErrorsChecked, value, () => OnlyMusicWithoutErrorsChecked);
            if (OnlyMusicWithoutErrorsChecked)
                OnlyMusicWithErrorsChecked = false;
            RaisePropertyChanged("AdditionalCriteriaHeader");
            if (!_filteringData) 
                SelectData();
        }
    }
```

The question is: can I use only one property nullable bool to do this job?

Comment: Why are you using check boxes if you want behaviour like radio button? I think instead of trying a work-around on check boxes, you might want to reconsider your choice of control itself.

Comment: A part is like radiobutton but I want to have the possibility that both checkboxes/radiobuttons are not selected. That's why, I want to bind them to a nullable bool property

Comment: In that case, using `Nullable` property is not a good idea. `Nullable` bool is a tristate property and the third value is an indeterminate state (null), which you don't want to use as a work around for your requirement. I believe first you have to figure out the control flow, i.e. how the sequence of states flow between checkboxes? In other words, in what scenario, both becomes unchecked, one becomes checked, other becomes unchecked and so on. And then you can decide what data-type fits well for that state. May be an enum might do the job. But you have to let us know your complete requirement.

Answer (score 3):

You can bind both CheckBoxes to the same property `OnlyMusicWithErrorsChecked`, and in the second CheckBox add a converter that inverts the property's value:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding OnlyMusicWithErrorsChecked, Converter={StaticResource Inverter}}"></CheckBox>
```

This converter would look somewhat like:

```
public class Inverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool)
            return !((bool)value);
        else // Fallback
            return false;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** If you want to build a three-state-solution with only one bindable property, you'll need two converters (or one that can be parameterized):

```
public class MyConverter : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InvertProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Invert", typeof (bool), typeof (MyConverter), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool)));

    public bool Invert
    {
        get { return (bool) GetValue(InvertProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InvertProperty, value); }
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var val = (bool?) value;
        switch (val)
        {
            case true:
                return Invert;
                break;
            case false:
                return !Invert;
                break;
            case null:
                return false; // None of the checkboxes shall be active
                break;
        }
        // Fallback
        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var val = (bool)value;
        switch (val)
        {
            case true:
                return Invert;
                break;
            case false:
                return null;
                break;
        }
        // Fallback
        return false;
    }
}
```

The `Invert` property is set to `false` for the first checkbox, and `true` for the second one:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MyConverter x:Key="Converter" Invert="False"/>
    <local:MyConverter x:Key="Inverter" Invert="True"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Now you can use these two converter instances to bind the checkboxes to the same property:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding MyProperty, Converter={StaticResource Converter}}" />
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding MyProperty, Converter={StaticResource Inverter}}" />
```

If the first box is checked the property will be `false`, if the second one is checked it will be `true`, and if no checkbox is checked it will be `null`.

However, I agree with ANewGuyInTown that you'd be better off with an `Enum`, since the `bool` types are a bit confusing here (by the way, most of the converter can be re-used when working with a three-state enum instead of nullable boolean).

Comment: I want to have the checkbox TheeState. So both not checked or one of them checked. Your solution is not for ThreeState checkboxes, isn't?

Comment: Of course, you can add any logic to the converter - I've edited my answer to show a three-state-solution!

Answer (score 2):

Make a "NotConverter" on one of the checkboxes. Here's my implementation I've been using for a while in Windows Store and Phone apps. WPF is similar.

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts a bool to it's oppisite and back.
/// </summary>
public sealed class NotConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return (!(value is bool)) || !(bool)value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return (value is bool) && (bool)value;
    }
}
```

Register your converter in your App.xaml (or your view) file:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converters:NotConverter x:Key="NotConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Bind it in your view:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding OnlyMusicWithErrorsChecked,Converter={StaticResource NotConverter}}"></CheckBox>
```

You could also name your other checkbox and bind to it's property like this:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="MyCheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding OnlyMusicWithErrorsChecked}"/>
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=MyCheckBox,Path=IsChecked,Converter={StaticResource NotConverter}}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Three state checkbox.

```
 public bool CheckBox1
    {
        get { return _checkBox1; }
        set 
        { 
            _checkBox1 = value;
            if (value == true)
            {
                CheckBox2 = false;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("CheckBox1");
        }
    }

    private bool _checkBox2 = false;

    public bool CheckBox2
    {
        get { return _checkBox2; }
        set 
        { 
            _checkBox2 = value;
            if (value == true)
            {
                CheckBox1 = false;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("CheckBox2");
        }
    }
```

In Xaml Code something like this

```
<CheckBox Content="CheckBox1" IsChecked="{Binding CheckBox1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="30" Width="100" />
<CheckBox Content="CheckBox2" IsChecked="{Binding CheckBox2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="30" Width="100" />
```

Comment: Ok, I did it. But you use also two properties. I thought maybe can I do that only with one nullable property (Checkbox1 checked when nullable bool property true, Checkbox2 checked when nullable bool property false and none Checkbox checked when nullable bool property null)

Comment: If you need to use a signle property, you should use converters as others suggested and place the similar logic.